# CRM 2011 SDK - get underlying IOrganizationService from service context

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have generated ServiceContext for my CRM organization. I'm able to connect to CRM properly. Since I have all my context configuration in app.config file, I wonder is it possible to get IOrganizationService from already instantiated OrganizationServiceContext?

Comment: Is from within a plugin? Or external code?

Comment: External code. I have an instance of context and I wonder if I can get IOrganizactionService from that context, so I don't have to instantiate again.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to access the *service* reference from multiple places, I usually do it in two steps. First of all I try to see if it's possible to pass it down to the called methods (I'm assuming that you have something like the following).

```csharp
using (IOrganizationService service 
  = (IOrganizationService) new OrganizationServiceProxy(...))
{
  DoSomething();
  DoSomething(service);
}

private void DoSomething(IOrganizationService service) { ... }
```

When it fails (due to technical setup or just plain dumbness), I set up a private property and in the constructor (or at least the first calling method) assign it a value for future access like this.

```csharp
class MyClass
{
  private IOrganization _service;
  private IOrganization _Service
  {
    get
    {
      if(_service == null)
        _service = (IOrganizationService) new OrganizationServiceProxy(...);
      return _service;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

And if you have a lot of code that operates on the server, you might want to move all that stuff to a separate class and have the calls made to it (with the property setup discussed above).

I'm not fully sure if I got your question correctly so be nice if I'm missing your point.

Comment: I'm not instantiating IOrganizationService nor OrganizationServiceProxy - I have generated data context from svcutil.exe, and I instantiate this context. I'd like to know if it's possible to extract IOrganizationService from that context to avoid double instantiatiom.

Comment: Cool. Never done it that way. How's the code for it and what do you have in the object created? Or am I misunderstanding totally?